# Cheeses and rice! Meta Equivalents of Single Word Requests

Tags: discussion

A lot of users here, myself included, find most SWRs of poor quality and sometimes downright annoying (although occasionally they prove entertaining.)

I thought Meta was supposed to be used for problems with the site:

> Meta English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of English Language & Usage Stack Exchange rather than discussing English language and usage itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does. Meta is for...
>
> ...English Language & Usage Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other about English Language & Usage Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)
>       ...English Language & Usage Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features), and
>       ...Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect the whole network)

Lately (or maybe since the beginning, I don't know, and I don't want to investigate; it would be too depressing) I see questions of a quality similar to SWRs on the main site, e.g.,

> Why did I get downvotes on my well received post? (I don't deserve this! Damn this site!)
>   Why did my comment get removed? (It was really, really useful and should remain for posterity! Damn this site!!)
>   Why was I suspended again‽ (I mean, I know I've been rude and uncooperative, but really, a suspension? Damn this site!!!)
>   This site is soooo unfriendly! (I've only been here for three days, but already I'm fed up! Damn this site!)
>   I raised a flag! Why hasn't a moderator acted on it? (Lazy mods! Damn this site!)
>   Comments with down votes should be mandatory! (Otherwise how can I <strike>argue and retaliate</strike> improve my question? Damn this site!)
>   Why was my f****** expletive asterisized? (People are so d***ed touchy! D*** this site!)

Three questions:

Are these kinds of questions really on topic for this site's meta?

Can we have one sufficient answer and close all the subsequent similar questions as dupes?

Can we migrate these types of questions (with appropriate edits) to SE Meta? (Or to chat? <- That would be nice.)

Comment: #1 I think it is encouraged to make problems like this known through meta, especially if the problem has been flagged and there was no response. #2 I don't these can be considered duplicates given they are each about very specific distinct situations (that one author's problem). #3 I think they're are on topic on meta.ELU, not meta.SE, if they are on topic at all.

Comment: First: +1. Second: the answer is yes, these questions are on topic on Meta, because it is the designated place to air grievances, and I don't want to live in a community where there is no designated place to air grievances. That would be downright scary. Third: that said, I think this post is a good reminder and exhortation to individual users to reflect on the decision to air a grievance, and what they'd like to accomplish by doing so, before they post. In other words, this isn't a question of site rules, but personal regulation.

Comment: @Mitch - Really? If someone wants to complain about a DV, they should bring it to meta? How many times can certain issues be brought up before there is a sufficient answer to which to link ("comments with DV...")?

Comment: It seems to me that Meta doesn't get overwhelmed with too many questions the way the main site does.  Sometimes questions about specific complaints or grievances can lead to productive discussion, if only in the comments.  My personal stance would be *if it ain't broke, don't fix it.*

Comment: @anongoodnurse Complaining about a couple of DVs seems a little ... complainy ('maybe it's you dude') but seriously wondering about what to do to counteract DV's is a good open attempt to fix things. But DVs are particular to the question and are not generic, so a new question every time seems appropriate.

Comment: @Mitch My general response to the inevitable handfuls of downvotes is ... they're inevitable. People honestly should just *expect* them. Now if it's more than a handful, and a question one views as perfectly acceptable is negatively scored, or there's a tension between up-and downvotes that tends to keep its net score hovering near zero, then it's worth asking about. If one cares to save the question, that is.

Comment: Should I know what "cheeses and rice" means?  I can make a phonetic guess at cheeses, but rice?

Comment: @ab2 It's a classic quick nutritious meal for sick kids. Also a euphemism for "Jesus Christ"

Comment: Is the euphemistic usage of "cheese and rice" potentially offensive? Should we avoid using it in titles?

Comment: @Josh - Maybe that should be a meta question...

Comment: We need a meta.meta.stackexchange...

Comment: @DanBron Your comments on meta are top quality. They're far better than my (hastily written) answers. I wish you'd post them as answers because otherwise most visitors won't see it. :)

Comment: If what you "thought Meta was supposed to be used for" is accurate and comprehensive, isn't this Meta question off-topic for Meta?

Comment: @JEL Your comment is on-topic for meta meta meta ELU. ;)

Comment: #3 Don't migrate shit.

Comment: When you say "D*** this site" after having said multiple times "Damn this site", I'm curious, what 4 letter word starting with 'D' needs to be redacted? 'Durn'? 'Dang'?

Comment: @Mitch - It was about a particular meta complaint...

Comment: @Mitch I had the same question!

Comment: @JEL - that is not an honest interpretation of the question. My position is that low quality questions (e.g. "We should have mandatory comments with down votes"/"Why did I get a down vote"/etc.) have been asked again and again (and again), and are not really doing much except muddying up meta. We can have a dupe with all the information with which to close it. No need to hash this over with every new user, is there? Or every high-rep user, or every suspended user who complains of mistreatment after answering to the mods, "Fuck you."

Comment: Oh, okay; it was an honest misinterpretation of the question. I simply didn't know if you considered your list comprehensive for questions on Meta. It seemed you did consider the list of topics for Meta, as you presented it, comprehensive, but if you say you don't, then you don't. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Why did I get downvotes on my well received post? (I don't deserve this! Damn this site!)
2. Why did my comment get removed? (It was really, really useful and should remain for posterity! Damn this site!!)
3. Why was I suspended again‽ (I mean, I know I've been rude and uncooperative, but really, a suspension? Damn this site!!!)
4. This site is soooo unfriendly! (I've only been here for three days, but already I'm fed up! Damn this site!)
5. I raised a flag! Why hasn't a moderator acted on it? (Lazy mods! Damn this site!)
6. Comments with down votes should be mandatory! (Otherwise how can I argue and retaliate improve my question? Damn this site!)
7. Why was my f****** expletive asterisized? (People are so d***ed touchy! D*** this site!)

---

**Are these kinds of questions really on topic for this site's meta?**

Yes, because this is what they mean:

1. I don't understand what downvotes mean or how they are used.
2. I don't understand how comments are meant to be used.
3. I don't understand how the suspension system works.
4. I don't understand what the community expectation is, so I don't know why I'm not fitting in here.
5. I don't understand how flagging works, especially when combined with moderation.
6. I have policy change suggestion and I don't know about Meta.SE or how to search Meta.SE.
7. I don't understand the policy for censoring question titles.

All of these topics are appropriate as they are essentially questions about how the site works.

---

**Can we have one sufficient answer and close all the subsequent similar questions as dupes?**

We can. We often do.

---

**Can we migrate these types of questions (with appropriate edits) to SE Meta? (Or to chat? <- That would be nice.)**

With enough votes, you surely could. However, most of these concern local policies and customs, so moving them to Meta.SE would not help the OP find an answer. Moving them to chat would make it harder to find for future users.

Comment: These questions often have little to do with learning how the site works but a lot to do with simply complaining about the site. I sometimes look at a new (complaining and meta posting) user's network profile to find they have high rep on other sites, so they should be familiar with how SE works. Also, I follow multiple sites and have seen problem users suspended from one site for certain violations only to move to another site I happen to follow, and see the same "information seeking" questions and behavior repeated at the new site. Etc. I don't mind posts genuinely seeking enlightenment.

Comment: But this is a good answer (one I should agree with if I were less cynical) so, +1.

Comment: I don't disagree that often these questions are often for gaining sympathy from the community, but at the heart of the complaints are legitimate Meta issues that can be addressed so that future users gain a better understanding of how the site works.

Answer (score 11):

> Are these kinds of questions really on topic for this site's meta?

Sure. These issues pop up on ELU. So... ELU meta to the rescue!

> Can we have one sufficient answer and close all the subsequent similar questions as dupes?

Not an ideal solution. Most titles may seem similar, but the questions usually are about different main site questions. There's no one size that fits all.

> Can we migrate these types of questions (with appropriate edits) to SE Meta? (Or to chat? <- That would be nice.)

Technically, we can. [But why?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4smXP46tG4) Unless it's a network-wide issue, do not migrate it to MSE. Site-specific metas exist for a reason.

If an extended discussion happens, moving to chat is necessary. Otherwise, don't. Chat is not well equipped to resolve queries. Not everyone frequents chat.

Comment: Chat is where I first ventured to ask why I was down voted without a comment so many years (it seems) ago. I was given a perfectly good explanation; it was very helpful, and since then, I accept down votes for what they are, indicative of disagreement, a bad answer, a bad attitude (sometimes mine), whatever. Chat is very useful.

Comment: Chat is definitely very useful. But I'm talking in general. We should not make chat the primary platform to resolve queries. Why do we need a meta then? The Q&A format is what helps people get straight to the answers without all the yada yada of chat rooms. :) @anongoodnurse

Comment: I should stop answering these meta stuff for a while. It's actually getting monotonous.

Comment: As are the questions... that's the point, right?